Trouble with an SSL cert. Works for most people, but a few are saying chrome is giving them SSL errors
My domain https://synic.dev is working for most people, but some are reporting SSL errors with Chrome. I don't believe it's a browser cache problem because they haven't visited the site before.
https://www.digicert.com/help/ reports that it's fine. Other domains that point to the same server work fine (like https://adamthings.me and https://invalidhandle.lol) - no one is reporting problems with these.
Running openssl s_client -connect synic.dev:443 -verify 8 -servername synic.dev gives this output:
verify depth is 8
Connecting to 74.207.232.118
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
verify return:1
depth=0 CN=synic.dev
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN=synic.dev
   i:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Nov 25 19:55:29 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 23 19:55:28 2025 GMT
 1 s:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
   i:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 384 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Mar 13 00:00:00 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Mar 12 23:59:59 2027 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN=synic.dev
issuer=C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2396 bytes and written 400 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocol: TLSv1.3
Server public key is 256 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Claude AI reports that output looks ok.
For context, I used certbot to create the SSL sertificate: certbot certonly --force-renew -d www.synic.dev -d synic.dev
The first time I created it I had a typo, so I had to redo it (not sure if that makes any difference). This happened about a month ago.
Nginx configuration looks like this:
server {
    server_name synic.dev www.synic.dev;
    root /home/web/synic.dev/;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/web/synicworld;
    }

    location /static/ {
        expires 1y;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000/";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/synic.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/synic.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

Any ideas here?

Some times  the users have the proper CA in place so that is why sometimes some random users could start having that kind of behavior

try checking with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ - perhaps you'll see it's not necessarily a chrome issue - i.e. the certificate sent over IPv6 is issued to backcountrypacking.com

Could you post the Chrome error?

@Bravo that was it, ssl v6 configuration was wrong. If you add that as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

It looks like your ipv6 server is serving the wrong ceritficate or your DNS is pointing to the wrong IPV6 address.
jasen@crackle:~$ openssl s_client -connect synic.dev:443 -verify 8 -servername synic.dev
verify depth is 8
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E6
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = backcountrypacking.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = backcountrypacking.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E6
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Nov 17 18:11:42 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 15 18:11:41 2025 GMT

